# How can I generate an indices array from an array of vertices (webgl)

Tags: javascript, webgl, indices, vertices

I need some help with generating indices from an array of vertices to draw gl.TRIANGLES in webGL.

I am currently using a custom QuadTree implementation to generate vertices that (as an example) could have the following positions:

```
*    *    *

*    *     

*         *
```

The positions of these vertices is only affected in the x-z plane, meaning they don't have any height (this will be generated in a later step);

My problem is that I haven't found any way to generate the indices to connect the vertices in order to draw the triangles.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Without any additional knowledge this will be impossible. There is a large amount of possible ways how these vertices could be connected (leading to different surfaces). How do you define which way you want them to be connected?

Comment: @BDL I don´t care how they are connected, as long as no triangles overlaps each other and as long as all vertices are used in at least one triangle. Since I know that the generated vertices are always positioned in a grid-like way, there must be some way to create triangles between them.

Comment: @J.Ryd Your comment explains the question and helps understanding it. So please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Tesselate function from turf package can make triangles out of polygon coordinates: http://turfjs.org/docs/#tesselate